# Global Error channel not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

Hey so i'm trying to use the global error channel in spring integration java dsl and it doesn't seem to be working.

I tried a small sample with a gateway where i pass a string and the handle just errors out:

```
@MessagingGateway
public interface SampleGateway {

    @Gateway(requestChannel="flow.input", replyTimeout=100000)
    public String upperCaseMe(Object input);

}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow flow() {
    return new IntegrationFlow() {
        @Override
        public void configure(IntegrationFlowDefinition<?> flow) {
            flow.handle(new GenericHandler<Object>() {
                @Override
                public Object handle(Object payload, Map<String, Object> headers) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("boom");
                }
            });
        }
    };
}
```

Then i made a flow to catch all errors and just print something if it reaches there:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow errorFlow() {
    return  IntegrationFlows
                .from("errorChannel")
                .handle(new MessageHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void handleMessage(Message<?> arg0) throws MessagingException {
                        System.out.println("Worked");
                    }
                })
                .get();
}
```

But the control never reaches to the error flow when i run the program. The error just ripples back all the way to the gateway and prints a stack trace.

I tried to explicitly create an `errorChannel` but even that doesn't seem to make a difference.

Am i missing something here? Or do i have to configure it differently for java dsl?

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the error channel to the gateway to enable its use. `errorChannel = "errorChannel"` on the `@MessagingGateway`.

See the javadocs...

```
/**
 * Identifies a channel that error messages will be sent to if a failure occurs in the
 * gateway's proxy invocation. If no {@code errorChannel} reference is provided, the gateway will
 * propagate {@code Exception}s to the caller. To completely suppress {@code Exception}s, provide a
 * reference to the {@code nullChannel} here.
 * @return the suggested channel name, if any
 */
String errorChannel() default "";
```

Comment: oh that works ya. But the docs say that when a message doesn't have an error channel in the header, it goes to a global error channel right?
http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/configuration.html#namespace-errorhandler

Comment: That is true when a message is handed off to another thread (via a queue channel or executor channel) but we need to give gateway callers the choice of exception propagation since the default `errorChannel` will simply log and consume the exception. I'll add some clarification to the docs.

Comment: Okay got it. So there's no one catch-all error channel which encompasses all flows then. Thanks!